# Transaction from customFragment to customFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show ProfileFragment(CustomFragment) when tapped on a button inside another CustomFragment(ChatListFragment), The Code I'm using gives me error;

```
Fragment f = null;
f=(Fragment)new Profile();
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, f.getFragmentManager()).commit();
```

Error I'm getting is **Incompatible types**

```
Required : com.android.Fragment
Found: com.myapp.ui.Profile
```

Comment: Your "com.myapp.ui.Profile" should extend "Fragment" class

Comment: please post the full fragment

Comment: @KonstantinsBogdanovs "com.myapp.ui.Profile"  extends to "CustomFragment which extends to Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Fragment f = new Profile();
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, f).commit();
```

Comment: That's but I am using but there is no ProfileFragment() instead I'm using Profile()

Comment: Ok use Profile() instead ProfileFragment() and try it.